# How to access database in lightswitch in other class?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, visual-studio-lightswitch, ls, light

I just don't know how to explain this clearly. So I create a simple image pattern of what I did.

My question is, how would I be able to access my database in other class in LS?

I've been searching on net, but I didn't found any solution. I hope I'll find it here.

Thanks!.
[image]

Any suggestion is already appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Bryan, but I found the answer on my problem here [Richard Waddell](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/19/LightSwitch-Creating-a-Relationship-on-current-User-through-SecurityData-UserRegistrations-Table.aspx)

Here is what I did to achieve my goal.

1. Switch your LS project to file view
2. Go to "Common" project, under "UserCode" folder, create a class (e.g. `Authenticate.cs`) and put this codes.

The code follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public class Authenticate
    {
        public static adminuser GetCurrentUser()
        {
            adminuser userFound = (from useritem in 
            Application.Current.CreateDataWorkspace().basecampcoreData.adminusers
            where useritem.LoginID == Application.Current.User.Name
            select useritem).SingleOrDefault();

            if (userFound != null)
                return userFound;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can now call the `Authenticate.GetCurrentUser()` anywhere in the project.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the first set of code that works is running inside a screen. For your Authenticate class, you need to do the following steps to access the Database.

**Note:** I'm assuming that your datasource has the default name of ApplicationData since you hid the name, if not, make the corresponding changes. If it's a completely different datasource, change "_IntrinsicData" in the steps below)

These steps are taken from the [Lightswitch Help Website](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/47/WCF-RIA-Service-Combining-Two-Tables.aspx)

> 1. Navigate to ..ServerGenerated\GeneratedArtifacts (in the LightSwitch project) and click on ApplicationData.cs and Add As Link.
> 2. Add the following code below, this code dynamically creates a connection to the database. LightSwitch uses “_IntrinsicData” as it’s connection string.

```
    private ApplicationDataObjectContext m_context;
    public ApplicationDataObjectContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.m_context == null)
            {
                string connString =
                    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["_IntrinsicData"].ConnectionString;
                EntityConnectionStringBuilder builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.Metadata =
                    "res://*/ApplicationData.csdl|res://*/ApplicationData.ssdl|res://*/ApplicationData.msl";
                builder.Provider =
                    "System.Data.SqlClient";
                builder.ProviderConnectionString = connString;
                this.m_context = new ApplicationDataObjectContext(builder.ConnectionString);
            }
            return this.m_context;
        }
    }
```

You should be able to access it through `Context.adminusers`